# How to redirect URLs starting with a certain path via TYPO3's redirects module?

Tags: regex, redirect, typo3, typo3-9.x

I would like to redirect any URL that start with /oldpath/ and i assume that i will need regular expressions.

Examples:

- */oldpath/* should be redirected.
- */oldpath/something* should be redirected.
- *something/oldpath/* should **not** be redirected.

I have activated "regular expressions" and tried the following inputs in "Source Path":

```
/oldpath/
```

… does not work as I would like. Everything containing /oldpath/ will be redirected, even if it is not starting with /oldpath/.

```
^/oldpath/(.*)$
```

… does nothing.

What would be the correct regular expression?

Comment: Try `#^oldpath/(.*)#` or `#^/oldpath/(.*)#`. You do not need any `$` since `.*` is greedy. You only need `(.*)` if you need to refer to this capture anywhere further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the regular expression for redirects between `#`s. So yours should be `#^/oldpath/(.*)$#`, though `#^/oldpath/#` also works.

Comment: Thanks, this works great. What are the # for or how did you know?

Comment: The placeholder if the field is empty shows an example with this. I ran into this yesterday and looked up why this was done. Regex can either be between `/`s or `#`s. I did not know this and always used `/`. In case of a path `#` is easier, because you don't have to escape the `/`s in the path. `/^\/oldpath\//` will also work though.

Comment: Thanks. I did not see the placeholder because I migrated the data from another table (ext:ods_redirects) and the field was already prefilled with old data :-)

Comment: Thanks.. I did it for route like this **#/(?:\b|-)([1-9]{1,2}[0]?|100)\b#**